# Enjoy a wide range of applications

Tags: traduction, anglais, science, université

Comment peut-on traduire

> Enjoy a wide range of applications

?

Par example

> Continuum mechanics enjoys a wide range of applications.
>
> La mécanique des milieux continus bénéficie d'un grand éventail d'applications.

Google translate donne bénéficier mais je me demande si c'est une bonne interprétation.

Comment: Cela pourrait s'entendre avec *bénéficier*. Maintenant, formellement, ce sont plus les applications qui *bénéficient* d'une science / connaissance que l'inverse. J'utiliserais alors préférentiellement le verbe *offrir*.

Comment: *Large éventail* est plus idiomatique que *grand éventail* : **La mécanique des milieux continus dispose d'un [ou offre un/ permet un] large éventail d'applications**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> grand éventail

n'est pas utilisé, la forme idiomatique est

> large éventail

Je vois 3 verbes qui pourraient fonctionner dans ce contexte

> La mécanique des milieux continus offre un large éventail d'applications.
>
> La mécanique des milieux continus ouvre un large éventail d'applications.
>
> La mécanique des milieux continus permet un large éventail d'applications.

ou tout simplement

> La mécanique des milieux continus a un large éventail d'applications.

on pourrait aussi remplacer « large éventail » par

> grand champs

Comment: Le "permet" du commentaire de jlliagre est aussi une bonne option. De plus, toujours sur sa remarque, "large éventail" me paraît en effet moins étrange que "grand éventail", à priori car plus idiomatique

Comment: @LaurentS. tu as raison, j'édite ma question pour inclure tout ça ;)

Answer (score 2):

Dans cette phrase, j'utiliserais volontiers le verbe *connaître*:

> La mécanique des milieux continus connaît un large éventail d'applications.

Answer (score 1):

Un certain nombre des notions que l'on trouve en traduction, comme d'ailleurs celle que confère « to enjoy », sont je pense plus ou moins déplacées vis-à-vis du contexte qui est essentiellement celui des chose inanimées.

1. *bénéficier* : jouir profiter
2. *offrir* : Action de donner quelque chose à quelqu'un
3. *permettre* :  Rendre possible, faire que quelque chose soit réalisable

Sont acceptables les verbes suivants, tous avec un sens figuré:

- *ouvrir*, *ouvrir sur*, *avoir*, *déboucher sur*, *conduire à*

Une traduction possible:

« La mécanique des milieux continus débouche sur un grand éventail d'applications. »,

ou bien en utilisant une [alternative](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grand+%C3%A9ventail%2Clarge+%C3%A9ventail&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrand%20%C3%A9ventail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clarge%20%C3%A9ventail%3B%2Cc0) de nos jours préférée pour « grand éventail »<sup>1</sup> , qui ne se trouverait que peu au sens figuré,

« La mécanique des milieux continus débouche sur un large éventail d'applications. »

<sub>1</sub> <sub>Il n'est pas nécessaire à mon avis de faire de « large éventail » une locution figée; il me semble que des combinaisons telles que « éventail étendu » et « vaste éventail » devraient être tolérées; pourquoi ne pas prendre en compte une variété de magnitudes qui dans la réalité ne manquent pas de se manifester. Par exemple, l'éventail n'a pas à être large et il peut être plutôt le contraire; dans ce cas, faudra t-il dire « un éventail étroit » ou « un petit éventail »?  Est-ce qu'« éventail restreint » sera à éviter? Je crois vraiment préférable de laisser la possibilité à l'utilisateur du langage de choisir ses nuances.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

L'extrait suivant, tiré de Scientific Computing with MATLAB and Octave [enter link description here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-45367-0) :

> Since F is a proper subset of R, elementary algebraic operations on
> floating-point numbers do not **enjoy** all the properties of analogous
> operations on R. Precisely, commutativity still holds for addition
> (that is fl(x + y) = fl(y + x)) as well as for multiplication (fl(xy)
> = fl(yx)), but other properties such as associativity and distributivity are violated.

a été rendu, comme suit, dans la [traduction en français](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Calcul_Scientifique/zctJAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Comme%20F%20est%20un%20sous-ensemble%20propre%20de%20R,%20les%20op%C3%A9rations%20alg%C3%A9briques%20%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaires%20sur%20F%20ne%20jouissent%20pas%20des%20m%C3%AAmes%20propri%C3%A9t%C3%A9s%20que%20sur%20R.%20La%20commutativit%C3%A9%20est%20satisfaite%20par%20l%E2%80%99addition&pg=PA6&printsec=frontcover) :

> Comme F est un sous-ensemble propre de R, les opérations algébriques
> élémentaires sur F ne **jouissent** pas des mêmes propriétés que sur R.
> La commutativité est satisfaite par l’addition (c’est-à-dire fl(x + y) =
> fl(y+x)) ainsi que par la multiplication (fl(xy) = fl(yx)), mais d’autres
> propriétés telles que l’associativité et la distributivité sont violées.